# Метод reverse, нужно перевернуть не строку, а каждую букву в слове, с сохранением порядка слов

Tags: javascript, строки, функции, методы

```js
function revBySep(str, sep) {
    return str.split(sep).reverse().join(sep);
}

var str = "I want to become a JavaScript Ninja!";
console.log(revBySep(str, "")); 
console.log(revBySep(str, " "));
```

в первом консоле `!ajniN tpircSavaJ a emoceb ot tnaw I` - вот тут все корректно как я хочу
во втором должно быть `I tnaw ot emoceb a tpircSavaJ !ajniN` - вот тут должен получить такой ввывод, подскажите, где я не там свернул)

Answer (score 1):

Функция написана правильно, но использована неверно.

```
function revBySep(str, sep) {
  return str.split(sep).reverse().join(sep);
}
```

При вызове, она создает **локальную** переменную `str`, которая не имеет никакого отношения к внешней строке. Получила строку - вернула другую строку. Дважды вызывая её - вы никуда не сохраняете результат первого вызова, и получаете два независимых результата от сработвашей функции.

Вместо исходной строки, во второй вызов функции нужно отправить результат вызова первой:

```js
function revBySep(str, sep) {
  return str.split(sep).reverse().join(sep);
}

var str = "I want to become a JavaScript Ninja!";

let step_1 = revBySep(str, "");
let step_2 = revBySep( step_1 , " ");

console.log(step_1);
console.log(step_2);
```

Comment: О, этот ответ правильней моего, я просто не понял, что два вызова связаны и работают на одну цель.

Answer (score 0):

Боюсь, у вас не выйдет обойтись здесь одной функцией. Для второго случая нужно отдельно пройтись по каждому слову:

```js
function revBySep(str, sep) {
    return str.split(sep)
      .map(word => [...word].reverse().join(''))
      .join(sep);
}

var str = "I want to become a JavaScript Ninja!";
console.log(revBySep(str, " "));
```

Comment: В первом случае вы полностью переворачиваете полученный массив символов, но во втором случае первичный массив переворачивать не нужно, нужно внутри этого массива переворачивать подмассивы символов в словах, поэтому всё усложняется.

Comment: большое спасибо, подозревал об этом, но так как новичок еще, думал есть один подход.

Comment: Удачного дальнейшего освоения языка)

Comment: Всё таки вышло)

Comment: Да, я не понял, что два вызова функции — это цепочка шагов для достижения цели.